# I'm making a roguelike in visual c++ 2010, how can I speed up the print rate?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a roguelike game in visual c++ 2010, which involves printing out a screen every time the player makes a move.  Unfortunately, it uses 8000 characters, and so it takes a second or so to print them out every refresh.  It might not seem like much, but given the number of moves involved in the game, it adds up.

I've tried unsyncing with stdio, compiling all the characters into a string and then printing the string with cout, and printing the characters with _putch();, but there was still a significant printing time for each method.  I tried printing out an unchanging string repeatedly to test if it was something else causing the delay, but there was still a delay when the only task was printing.

My question is, is there anything I could try that could potentially speed up the process?  A friend of mine suggested ncurses, would that be worth a try?  If so, how would I do it, and if not, what else could I try?

Comment: You'll probably have to do something platform-specific. I might suggest looking into using [`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682122(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686010(v=vs.85).aspx), and [`WriteConsoleOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404(v=vs.85).aspx). [Here is a demo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685032(v=vs.85).aspx). ncurses may work, but I've never tried it.

Comment: I would recommend you get away from the console entirely, and start working with actual raster graphics, perhaps using a library like SDL or SFML.

Comment: I don't have a lot of programming experience, so I don't know if a graphics library is something I can do : /

Comment: To increase *drawing* performance, reduce the amount of drawing.  For example, if you are moving one character, then move that character without redrawing the entire background.  You will need an external library that allows x,y positioning in a console.

Comment: Never used console for drawing complex scenes, but 1s for 8000 characters seems pretty slow. Printing a string of 8K chars and clearing the console afterwards 100 times on my systems (Win10 VS2015) takes about 25 seconds via `cout` and 13s via `printf`. can you show us an example of your code? But as Comstalks indicated, the standard output stream is probably the wrong tool for what you want to accomplish.anyway and you should have a look at the system specific functions that actually work with a console and not an abstract character stream.

Comment: [Here's a link](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044844545&id=1043284392) to get you going down one posible path for making Windows console app. Also, check out [this page from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x2hy4cx(VS.71).aspx). The trick is to draw only changes, not entire screen, at least most of the time.

Answer (score -1):

I would agree with cornstalks. However if you are looking to make a pure console game I would suggest you take advantage of the built in ctime library. Learn from a library (such as SDL1.2) or a source on how to handle hard-coding time based events with entity systems. There are many efficient ways to store these characters and print them in a jiff. Or you can use SDL and make the game window seem like a console and handle everything as raster-graphics.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this doesn't really answer the question asked. Your response might be okay if this were a normal discussion forum, but StackOverflow is a bit different and is a Q&A site. Answers should, generally, be complete and answer the question asked.